# How to correctly parse strings received from php

Tags: javascript

After a call to a php method that loads a value from a table, I am expected to be returned the number 10 but instead I get returned the following weird string:

```
string(1) "9" 10
```

How can I extract the value 10 alone? What kind of index does "9" represent? 
I have tried also with echo json_encode($newNo); in php but it shows an error.

**html:**

```
document.getElementById("output").value = this.responseText; //string(1) "9" 10
```

**php:**

```
$number = 9; 
$newNo = $number + 1;
echo $newNo;
```

Comment: You are probably `var_dump`ing the `$number` before you echo `$newNo`. Is this your entire code?

Comment: agreed this looks like output from a debugging command like var_dump. make sure there aren't any lurking in your PHP code by accident.

Comment: You are absolutely right! There was a var_dump higher up in the code that I had missed. Many thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity what is the meaning of (1) and "9" before the output value?